# Select all items for each category but only for latest date per each category

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Table schema is very simple `item`, `category` and `date`. I would like to query all items for each category but only for MAX date per each category.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(date) over (partition by category) as max_date
      from t
     ) t
where date = max_date;
```

Comment: This does the job! I was not aware of `partition by` statement

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL (*and in BigQuery style*)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY category
```

> I have cases where multiple entries have exactly same max date and all need to be returned

consider below version:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT t.* FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(arr ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1) arr FROM (
    SELECT category, `date`, ARRAY_AGG(t) arr
    FROM `project.dataset.table` t
    GROUP BY category, `date`
  ) GROUP BY category 
), UNNEST(arr) t
```

Comment: This seems like returns only one top result with max date. I have cases where multiple entries have exactly same max date and all need to be returned.

Comment: oh. ok, this was not clear to me - i thought it can be only one  - but obviously now this was wrong assumption :o)